# Gurobipy: How to add a constraint that limits the number of times a certain tupledict value can appear in the optimal solution?

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, gurobi

To explain myself with code, this is the data I'm using:

```
name, position, pp90, value = gp.multidict({
     ('Jordan'): [0, 3.68, 5.0],
     ('Bird'): [0, 3.61, 5.0],
     ('Johnson'): [1, 6.82, 6.0],
     ('Drexler'): [1, 6.61, 7.0],
     ('Olajuwon'): [1, 6.56, 7.5],
     ('Drexler'): [3, 5.03, 7],
     ('Ewing'): [3, 4.99, 5.5],
     ('Payton'): [3, 4.86, 7.5],
     ('Kemp'): [3, 4.75, 0],
     ('Stockton'): [3, 4.65, 0],
})
```

Here's my decision variable, maximizing objective function, and one of the constraints:

```
#Add the decision variable
player = m.addVars(name, obj=value, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="player")

# Set Objective since we are maximizing points the last argument here is GRB.MAXIMIZE
m.setObjective(quicksum(pp90[i]*player[i] for i in name), GRB.MAXIMIZE)

#Add the constraints
#the sum of player value cannot exceed 100 million
total_value = 100
m.addConstr(quicksum(value[i]*player[i] for i in name) <= total_value, name="total value");
```

Now the next constraint I want to add is that, the optimal solution can only consist of 2 names with the first value being 1 (i.e. out of Johnson, Drexler, Olajuwon, only 2 of them can be in the optimal solution).

Could anyone please help here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you only need to sum over all the players with value 1 and impose the constraint that this sum is less-equal than 2:

```py
P1 = [name for name, value in position.items() if value == 1]
m.addConstr(quicksum(value[i]*player[i] for i in P1) <= 2)
```

PS: There are two 'Drexler' in your multidict. Because keys inside a dict are assumed to be unique, you are overwriting the first 'Drexler' entry with the second one.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thank you for the quick answer! And thanks for the heads up regarding the dict key.